# How to open/create UIManagedDocument synchronously?

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, uimanageddocument

As mentioned in title, I would like to open `UIManagedDocument` synchronously, i.e, I would like my execution to wait till open completes. I'm opening document on mainThread only.

Current API to open uses block

```
[UIManagedDocument openWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL success))];
```

Locks usage mentioned at [link](http://omegadelta.net/2011/05/10/how-to-wait-for-ios-methods-with-completion-blocks-to-finish/) works well on threads other than main thread. If I use locks on `mainThread`, it freezes execution of app.

Any advice would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First, let me say that I **strongly discourage** doing this.  Your main thread just waits, and does nothing while waiting for the call to complete.  Under certain circumstances, the system will kill your app if it does not respond on the main thread.  This is highly unusual.

I guess you should be the one to decide when/how you should use various programming tools.

This one does exactly what you want... block the main thread until the completion handler runs.  Again, I **do not** recommend doing this, but hey, it's a tool, and I'll take the NRA stance: guns don't kill people...

```
__block BOOL waitingOnCompletionHandler = YES;
[object doSomethingWithCompletionHandler:^{
    // Do your work in the completion handler block and when done...
    waitingOnCompletionHandler = NO;
}];
while (waitingOnCompletionHandler) {
    usleep(USEC_PER_SEC/10);
}
```

Another option is to execute the run loop.  However, this isn't really synchronous, because the run loop will actually process other events.  I've used this technique in some unit tests.  It is similar to the above, but still allows other stuff to happen on the main thread (for example, the completion handler may invoke an operation on the main queue, which may not get executed in the previous method).

```
__block BOOL waitingOnCompletionHandler = YES;
[object doSomethingWithCompletionHandler:^{
    // Do your work in the completion handler block and when done...
    waitingOnCompletionHandler = NO;
}];
while (waitingOnCompletionHandler) {
    NSDate *futureTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:futureTime];
}
```

There are other methods as well, but these are simple, easy to understand, and stick out like a sore thumb so it's easy to know you are doing something unorthodox.

I should also note that I've never encountered a good reason to do this in anything other than tests.  You can deadlock your code, and not returning from the main run loop is a slippery slope (even if you are manually executing it yourself - note that what called you is still waiting and running the loop again could re-enter that code, or cause some other issue).

Asynchronous APIs are GREAT.  The condition variable approach or using barriers for concurrent queues are reasonable ways to synchronize when using other threads.  Synchronizing the main thread is the opposite of what you should be doing.

Good luck... and make sure you register your guns, and always carry your concealed weapons permit.  This is certainly the wild west.  There's always a John Wesley Harden out there looking for a gun fight.

Comment: ...thanks for your time. I tried to search old API opening documents without blocks. Any idea, how was that achieved?

Comment: UIManagedDocument is a relatively new interface, and I do not think it ever had a synchronous API.  Inside, it has two ManagedObjectContext objects... one on the main thread, and one using a private dispatch queue.  All the IO operations happen in the background, so the nature of the class dictates using an asynchronous API.  Before blocks, async APIs either used a delegate or notifications to let the caller know when the operation was complete.

Comment: this not work , when i try below code:
        __block BOOL waitingOnCompletionHandler = YES;
        [_managedDocument openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            if (success) {
                DLog(@"open document succeed!");
                self.managedObjectContext = _managedDocument.managedObjectContext;
                waitingOnCompletionHandler = NO;
            }
            }];
        while (waitingOnCompletionHandler) {
            usleep(USEC_PER_SEC/10);
        }
the main thread stuck there for ever...

Comment: @zolibra - The reason you are stuck in a deadlock is that the `completionHandler` actually has work to do in your case and it needs the main thread to do it. So it is blocked waiting on your already blocked main thread. This is part of why this is highly discouraged.