# How to ensure NSManagedObjectContext when opened asynchronously through UIManagedDocument

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have an application with different controllers that all operate on the same NSManagedObjectContext.

My approach was to initialize the NSManagedObjectContext in my AppDelegate and inject it into all the controllers.

I am initializing my NSManagedObjectContext by opening a UIManagedDocument like this:

```
UIManagedDocument* databaseDoc = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[databaseDoc.fileURL path]]) {
    [databaseDoc saveToURL:databaseDoc.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        myController.managedObjectContext = databaseDoc.managedObjectContext;
    }];
} else if (databaseDoc.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
    [databaseDoc openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        myController.managedObjectContext = databaseDoc.managedObjectContext;
    }];
} else if (databaseDoc.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal){
    myController.managedObjectContext = databaseDoc.managedObjectContext;
}
```

Now my problem is, that opening the UIManagedDocument happens asynchronously and the NSManagedObjectContext is only available in the completion block.

How do I ensure that the controllers always have a valid NSManagedObjectContext to work with? Of course the problems happen at startup i.e. when a controller wants to use the NSManagedObjectContext in his "viewDidLoad" method, and the completion block in the AppDelegate has not yet run ...

One approach would probably be to "wait" in the AppDelegate until the UIDocument has opened, but as far as I gather [this is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314190/how-to-open-create-uimanageddocument-synchronously) ...

I would like to avoid to "pollute" my controllers with code that deals with the asynchronous nature of opening a NSManagedObjectContext... but maybe this is a naive wish?

Comment: You should implement your uiviewcontroller managedObjectContext into a custom setter method (setManagedObjectContext:(context*){}). So even if the context doesn't exist when the viewDidload method is called, you can make your GUI logic method after the context is set when ur custom setter is called. Call this into your viewDidLoad method too. So that you're not bind to synchronizing stuff.

Comment: @Mr Bonjour Thanks for the tip. That is what I am doing currently, but that basically leads to "polluting" my viewcontroller: For instance when I have a button that creates a new NSManageObject, then I have to disable it first and then enable it when the NSManagedObjectContext is set ... I would like to avoid that, since the viewcontroller *only* has a reason to exist if it can rely on its NSManagedContext ...

Comment: Then you should be sure that your viewController is called only when your NSManagedContext is available. You can do this in setting a displayController at app launch time, then when your context is available, you can call your another viewController. Note that you can't get both your GUI and context available in the nearly same time, since they both getting there data asynchronously

Comment: @Mr Bonjour: Thanks. The suggestion of setting a displayContoller at app launch time sound interesting. Could you pleas elaborate that in a proper answer (that I then can accept as solution). I would be interested in how to accomplish this ... would this be the initial controller that then segues programmatically to the next application controller after initialization? How to wait in this "inizalizing contoller"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your appDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    MyWaitViewController* waitController = [[MyWaitViewController new] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController =  waitController;

// then somewheres else, when you get your context
  [databaseDoc saveToURL:databaseDoc.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        myContextController.managedObjectContext = databaseDoc.managedObjectContext;
        self.window.rootViewController    = myContextController;
        // note that at this point when the viewDidLoad method will get called
        // it will have his managedObjectContext and his view already available.
        // you can change your rootController, or push another viewController into the
 // stack. Depending on what u want from the GUI side

    }];
    return YES;
}
```

Note that you dispose the GUI logic into the MyWaitViewController + AppDelegate side. But you keep your "myContextController" away from that logic control, since he get called / created only when a context exist.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. However I am using a storyboard. I will have to investigate how your approach of setting the rootViewController programmatically would be compatible with using a storyboard...

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with the same issue, and I came up with it by using `NSNotificationCenter`.

- When initializing your `NSManagedObjectContext` in the success handler, add send a notification.
- Then, add a listener to to the `viewDidLoad` of whatever your first `ViewController` is.

I used that listener to call a `reloadData` method. In a heavy app, this could be a problem, as the `viewcontroller` loads blank, and then reloads the data, but this is a lite one, and it's noticeable at all - the `viewController` loads instantaneously with the `managedObjectContext`.