# Open UIDocument synchronously

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, uidocument

I am currently redesigning my existing app from CoreData storage to a document based app using `UIDocument` subclasses. This is mainly to be able to introduce iCloud synchronization, since there is ongoing issues with iCloud sync in CoreData.

At some places, I can easily replace the CoreData usage with corresponding `UIDocument` handling, at some places, however, I am really having a hard time to replace synchronous code with asynchronous code. Mainly when I need to open some documents on the fly, for only a quick access, for example during a calculation.

I already implemented e.g. dispatch groups, to wait for `UIDocument` operations, but in some places this just does not seem suitable. E.g. when alot of documents need to be opened in sequence to finish the calculation, this would result in a very complex and weird chaining of blocks and dispatch groups.

To better understand the problem, let me roughly describe what king of documents my app is using:

- One document per active user (different users can login/logout)
- One document per user + per year (app can display a selected year)
- Multiple data documents per user + per year
- Some more metadata documents which can all be loaded in memory only once (no problem here)

So basically, for 1 user, and 2 years of app usage, there can be around 50 documents which need to be displayed on demand, and used for calculation.

The user documents will always be opened and loaded into memory, I dont see issues here. For the other documents, its not so easy, because I need to load them on the fly, also probably documents from other users which are not currently active (this eliminates the possibility to load all documents for current user in memory).

So, **my main question is, what would be a good approach in handling a lot of documents?**

I bet it is a bad idea, to just load **all** documents into memory, also in respect to iCloud sync.

**Is there any synchronous API, or examples of forcing sync/synchronous API wrappers for `UIDocument`?**

Comment: I have no idea if this will help but heres [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10314190/2446155)

Answer (score 1):

You could open multiple documents synchronously by forcing the current thread to wait on a condition:

```
- (void)openDocumentsSynchronously:(NSArray *)documents
{
    __block NSUInteger waitingOnDocuments = documents.count;
    NSCondition *condition = [NSCondition new];

    for (UIDocument *document in documents)
    {
        [document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {

            waitingOnDocuments--;

            [condition lock];
            [condition broadcast];
            [condition unlock];
        }];
    }

    while (waitingOnDocuments > 0)
    {
        [condition lock];
        [condition wait];
        [condition unlock];
    }
}
```

I wouldn't recommend doing this on the main thread, though, as the documents might take a little while to open.